# Texture in Render not right

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, 3d-view

[image: Viewport]I cant figure out what is wrong with my rendering. The texture is fine in viewport but when I render it loses the color.

[image: render]

Comment: What render engine? Does the object have any material? [Edit] your question with more information

Comment: Cycles Render Engine and yes it has Materials.

Comment: This information is far from enough to answer your question. What is in those materials?

Comment: can I send you email of file?

Comment: Upload your .blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4054" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4054/)

Comment: Here is file[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4054" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4054/)

Answer (score 3):

In your material the texture is used only for the displacement input, so the color is a dull grey with bump effects.

The viewport is telling you the mapping of the texture, not the end result, which is a more complex task.

I added a copy of the image texture to feed Diffuse color shader.

Don't forget to set all color image texture as "color data" and all displacement or Black and white images as "Non color data".

[image]